# Anaconda in Pycharm Traceback (most recent call) error - importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, import, anaconda

I am new to python. I have downloaded anaconda and I just wanted to test importing a package into Pycharm. I know numpy is installed, because if I go into the anaconda terminal and type `pip install numpy` it says it is already installed. It is also included in the interpreter.

However, if I try run `import numpy as np` I receive the follow error message.

```
C:\Users\myname\anaconda3\envs\neuralnine\python.exe C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/anacondatest/test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/anacondatest/test", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\myname\anaconda3\envs\neuralnine\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Any idea on what is going wrong here? Many thanks! And apologies if more clarity is required, it is my first time posting so am unsure of the best way to express my queries. If you need any extra info, please just ask. (Also just to add, the neuralnine env is from this video - youtube.com/watch?v=hVcEv7rEN24&t=253s, but this error still occurred when I just followed these instructions - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html)

Comment: Did you try putting `anaconda %1 is not a valid win32 application` into a search engine?

Comment: I did, the main thing that came up was people deleting and reinstalling anaconda (I did this, no luck). I have the 64 bit version (since I am on a 64 bit machine). Should I try the 32 bit version? No clue why this is coming up.

Comment: Actually nvm found this - https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27693, fixed my issue, thank you